# Rails link_to do block gives `unexpected keyword_do_block` error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use a `link_to` block in Rails 2.3.14 with Ruby 1.9.3, and it's causing 
`ActionView::TemplateError syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block`

**HTML**

```
<% @contents.each do |item| %>

  <%= link_to "#" do %> # this is the line referenced in the error message
    <%= content_tag(:h3, item.title) %>
    <div class="details">
      # divs with text
    </div>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

**Detailed error message**

The lines of code included in the error message do not perfectly match the code included above, which I simplified for debugging, but you can see that the line referenced is the same.

```
ActionView::TemplateError (/my/file/_partial.html.erb:78: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block
...;@output_buffer.safe_concat((do).to_s);@output_buffer.safe_c...
...                               ^
/my/file/_partial.html.erb:97: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting keyword_end
');       else
              ^
/my/file/_partial.html.erb:123: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end) on line #78 of app/views/content/_list.html.erb:
75:                 <%= hoverhide_image(item) %>
76:               </div>
77:               <div class="hovershow">
78:                 <%= link_to("#") do %>
79:                   <%= content_tag(:h3, item.title) %>
80:                   <div class="details">
81:                     <div>
```

If I replace the `link_to` block with `a` tags, it renders perfectly.

If I remove the `=` from line 3 (making it `<% link_to "#" do %>` instead), no error is thrown, but of course my text doesn't render.

Any idea what's going on?

(edited to add more details on the error message)

Comment: what is the error message generated?

Comment: @ArupRakshit: `link_to` can be written with block.

Comment: Which is the exact line of the error (the one showed by the exception)? The code you posted is fine.

Comment: @AmanGarg - edited to add the details of the `unexpected keyword_do_block` error I mentioned in paragraph 1.

Comment: @akhanubis - The error is now referenced in the question text. It's giving an error on the line opening the `link_to` block.

Comment: Add the whole `my/file/_partial.html.erb`

Comment: @joanwolk in Rails 2.3 methods taking block should be called in view with `<%` instead of `<%=`. What does it mean that your text doesn't get rendered then?

Comment: @akhanubis - That's difficult, since it's a private project, and I'd need to anonymize all the other features of the code.

Comment: @MarekLipka - Good question! Thanks for clearing that up; I wasn't sure if that was a typo in the docs or not.